# Issues with powershell POST data using invoke-restmethod

Tags: powershell, http-post

I'm currently trying to create a `POST` request using PowerShell. this is my initial `hashArray`:

```
$hashArrayOfStrings = @(
@{
    criteria    = '"platform" = "iOS" AND "connected_at" >= "now-1d" AND "client.connected" >= "now-1d" AND "apns" = true AND ( "version" STARTS WITH "1" OR "version" STARTS WITH "2" )'
    name        = "iOS"
    description = "Description1"
},
@{
    criteria    = '“platform” = “android” AND “connected_at” >= “now-1d” AND ( “client.connected” < “now-1d” OR “apns” = false ) AND ( “version” STARTS WITH “1” OR “version” STARTS WITH “2” )'
    name        = "name2"
    description = "Description2"
})
```

This is the function to call the API:

```
function Call-API {
 param ($ID, $criteria, $name, $description)
$url = "$($global:apiURL)?id=1"
$body =@{ criteria = $criteria; name = $name; description = $description; SpaceId = $ID; static = $false }
(($body | ConvertTo-Json) -replace '"', '\"')
    try {
    $results = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $global:headers -Body $body -Method Post -ContentType "application/json"
        return $results.results
    }
    catch { Show-Error -errorInfo $_ }
```

Then I'm calling the function with this code:

```
$hashArrayOfStrings | ForEach-Object {
                try {
                    Call-API -ID $ID -criteria $_.criteria -name $_.name -description $_.description
                }
                catch { Show-Error -errorInfo $_ }
            }
```

Testing with cURL works:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxx' -H "Content-Type: application/json" 'https://apiurl.com?Id=1' --data-binary '{"name": "test","description": "test description.","SpaceId": 1,"static": false,"criteria": "(\"platform\"=\"Android\") AND \"apns\"=false"}'
```

and did some testing with python using requests and also works.

I think the problem is escaping the characters. the API is expecting a string in the data of POST.

I've tested with ` in front of each double quote symbol with the same result:

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HttpResponseException: Response status code does not indicate success: 405 (Method Not Allowed).
   at System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.ThrowTerminatingError(ErrorRecord errorRecord)
```

Comment: In the 8th line of  your first code block you have `“”` quotes and not `""`.

Comment: thank you for the edits @double-beep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: first of all I cannot test a solution because I cannot pass the query to a similar API, but after some tests the following seems to be you issue.

In Line 5 of you second block `Call-API` function you use `-replace` to escape `"`.

The `ConvertTo-Json` function in in PowerShell already escapes required chars in strings. Also note that PowerShell Handels non-converted JSON Objects as a string so doing `-replace '"', '\"'` will result as follows:

`(@{name = '"name"'} | ConvertTo-Json) -replace '"', '\"'`

output:

`{\"name\": \"\\"name\\"\"}`

which is not valid json. 
removing the `-replace` function outputs:

`{"name": "\"name\""}`

which is valid json

Apart from this you can use [PowerShell splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6) to make your function a easier to read/manage. Also if you are sure the passed hashtable is the same for the function just pass it as a whole and call the properties in the function.

```
$hashArrayOfStrings = @(
    @{
        criteria    = '"platform" = "iOS" AND "connected_at" >= "now-1d" AND "client.connected" >= "now-1d" AND "apns" = true AND ( "version" STARTS WITH "1" OR "version" STARTS WITH "2" )'
        name        = "iOS"
        description = "Description1"
    },
    @{
        criteria    = '“platform” = “android” AND “connected_at” >= “now-1d” AND ( “client.connected” < “now-1d” OR “apns” = false ) AND ( “version” STARTS WITH “1” OR “version” STARTS WITH “2” )'
        name        = "name2"
        description = "Description2"
    }
)

function Call-API($Id, $Object){
    $params = @{
        Uri     = "$($Global:apiURL)?id=1"
        Headers = $global:headers
        Method  = "POST"
        ContentType = "application/json" 
        Body    = @{
            SpaceId         = $Id
            static          = $false
            criteria        = $Object.critera
            name            = $Object.name
            $description    = $Object.description
        } | ConvertTo-Json
    }

    try{
        $Respose = Invoke-RestMethod @params
        return $Respose.results
    } catch {
        throw $_
    }
}

foreach($object in $hashArrayOfStrings){
    Call-API -Id $id -Object $object
    #you dont need a additional try catch here as this is embedded in your Call API function
}
```